# Bullet-proofing an email scheduler in C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking to bullet-proof this method. Specifically, I never want an item to be left without calling the following:

```
MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);
```

**The Method**

```
private static void SendMail(MailItemViewModel item)
    {

        var r = new MailItemRepository(); //  Repository
        var c = new CompanyRepository(); //  Repository

        try
        {

            var toAddresses = ((item.Mail_Recipient) ?? "").Split(';');
            var ccAddresses = ((item.Mail_CC) ?? "").Split(';');
            var bccAddresses = ((item.Mail_BCC) ?? "").Split(';');

            var totalAddresses = 0;

            var fotmattingInfo = c.GetMailHeaderFooterByCompany(item.CompanyId ?? 0);

            try
            {

                var attachments = r.GetMailAttachmentsByMailId(item.Mail_ID);
                var attachmentsCloud = r.GetMailAttachmentsCloudByMailId(item.Mail_ID).ToList();

                var mailMsg = new MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new MailAddress(item.MailAgent_FromEmail, item.MailAgent_FromName),
                    Subject = item.Mail_Subject,
                    SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                    Body = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", fotmattingInfo.Header, item.Mail_Body, fotmattingInfo.Footer),
                    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                };

                //attachments
                foreach (var att in attachments.Where(x => x.Filename != ""))
                    mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(att.Filename));

                foreach (var attCloud in attachmentsCloud.Where(x => x.DocumentId > 0))
                {
                    Stream s = new MemoryStream(LayerFiles.CloudFileMethods.GetUniqueFile("", attCloud.Document.CloudFileName));
                    mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(s, attCloud.Document.Document_Filename, attCloud.Document.Content_Type));
                }

                //client creds
                var basicAuthenticationInfo = new NetworkCredential(item.MailAgent_Username, item.MailAgent_Password);

                var client = new SmtpClient()
                {
                    Port = item.MailAgent_Port ?? 25,
                    Host = item.MailAgent_SMTP,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo,
                    EnableSsl = item.MailAgent_UseSSL ?? false
                };

                foreach (var addressTo in toAddresses.Where(x => x != "")) // to addresses
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mailMsg.To.Add(addressTo);
                        totalAddresses++;
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e0)
                    {
                        logger.Info(e0.Message);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var addressCC in ccAddresses.Where(x => x != "")) // cc addresses
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mailMsg.CC.Add(addressCC);
                        totalAddresses++;
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e1)
                    {
                        logger.Info(e1.Message);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var addressBCC in bccAddresses.Where(x => x != "")) // bcc addresses
                {

                    try
                    {
                        mailMsg.Bcc.Add(addressBCC);
                        totalAddresses++;
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e2)
                    {
                        logger.Info(e2.Message);
                    }
                }

                //For Synchronous Execution....
                client.Send(mailMsg);

                if (item.Mail_ID > 0)
                {
                    MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 3, "OK");
                }
            }

            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);

                if (item.TaskId != null)
                    TaskMethods.UpdateFailure(item.TaskId, true);


                logger.Info(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);

                if (item.TaskId != null)
                    TaskMethods.UpdateFailure(item.TaskId, true);

                logger.Info(ex.Message);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);

                if (item.TaskId != null)
                    TaskMethods.UpdateFailure(item.TaskId, true);

                logger.Info(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Info(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider refactoring this code. The method is too long and is "[arrow code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)"... in some places you even have a `try` inside a `try` inside a `try` - that really is too much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple things I would do:

- You can collapse your catch for SmtpException,
  NullReferenceException, and Exception into a single catch block,
  since all blocks have identical code.
- You can split off your handling of To, CC, and BCC addresses into a
  helper method that takes in the appropriate view model property and
  collection on the mail message, as all three sections of code are
  identical.
- Consider making your SendMail method a method on an object.  You can 
  split off the instantiation of the repository objects into a
  constructor of this object to clean up the SendMail some more.

Other notes:

- I left the totalAddresses variable in the SendMail method, though it
  doesn't look like it's useful.
- If it isn't useful, then feel free to remove it from both SendMail
  and ProcessAddressList. I'm not sure where the logger object is
  coming from.  It should probably be something injected into the
  class.
- I noticed an if check on mail ID being greater than 0 just after the
  send in order to say it had an OK status, but there is no code I saw
  at a glance that sets this ID.  If it should be set prior to the
  method, you should probably add a check on the ID at the top of the
  method and return early with a failure status if it is less than or
  equal to 0.
- I removed the nested try/catch, as it did not appear to provide much value.

Here is what I have thus far (over a lunch break, so bear with me on the time crunch ;)

```
public class MailHelper
{

public MailHelper ()
{
    MailRepo = new MailItemRepository();
    CompanyRepo = new CompanyRepository();
}

private MailItemRepository MailRepo { get; set; }
private CompanyRepository CompanyRepo { get; set; }

public void SendMail(MailItemViewModel item)
{
    try
    {
        var totalAddresses = 0;
        var fotmattingInfo = CompanyRepo.GetMailHeaderFooterByCompany(item.CompanyId ?? 0);

        var attachments = MailRepo.GetMailAttachmentsByMailId(item.Mail_ID);
        var attachmentsCloud = r.GetMailAttachmentsCloudByMailId(item.Mail_ID).ToList();

        var mailMsg = new MailMessage()
        {
            From = new MailAddress(item.MailAgent_FromEmail, item.MailAgent_FromName),
            Subject = item.Mail_Subject,
            SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            Body = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", fotmattingInfo.Header, item.Mail_Body, fotmattingInfo.Footer),
            BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        };

        foreach (var att in attachments.Where(x => x.Filename != ""))
            mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(att.Filename));

        foreach (var attCloud in attachmentsCloud)
        {
            if (attCloud.DocumentId <= 0)
                continue;

            var s = new MemoryStream(LayerFiles.CloudFileMethods.GetUniqueFile("", attCloud.Document.CloudFileName));
            mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(s, attCloud.Document.Document_Filename, attCloud.Document.Content_Type));
        }

        var basicAuthenticationInfo = new NetworkCredential(item.MailAgent_Username, item.MailAgent_Password);

        var client = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Port = item.MailAgent_Port ?? 25,
            Host = item.MailAgent_SMTP,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo,
            EnableSsl = item.MailAgent_UseSSL ?? false
        };

        totalAddresses += ProcessAddressList (item.Mail_Recipient, mailMsg.To);
        totalAddresses += ProcessAddressList (item.Mail_CC, mailMsg.CC);
        totalAddresses += ProcessAddressList (item.Mail_BCC, mailMsg.BCC);

        client.Send(mailMsg);
        MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 3, "OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleFailure (item, ex);
    }
}

private int ProcessAddressList (string addresses, MailAddressCollection addressCol)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (addresses))
      return 0;

   var totalAddresses = 0;
   var addressList = addresses.Split (';');

   foreach (var address in addressList)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (address))
           continue;

       try
       {
           addressCol.Add(address);
           totalAddresses++;
       }
       catch (FormatException ex)
       {
           logger.Info(ex.Message);
       }
   }

   return totalAddresses;
}

private void HandleFailure (MailItemViewModel item, Exception ex)
{
   MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);

   if (item.TaskId != null)
       TaskMethods.UpdateFailure(item.TaskId, true);

   logger.Info(ex.Message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `IDisposable` objects in `using` statements to ensure the proper disposal of unmanaged resources. I also did a few smaller things, like use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` (if not .NET 4, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`), for example.

```
    private static void SendMail(MailItemViewModel item)
    {
        var r = new MailItemRepository(); //  Repository
        var c = new CompanyRepository(); //  Repository

        try
        {
            var toAddresses = ((item.Mail_Recipient) ?? string.Empty).Split(';');
            var ccAddresses = ((item.Mail_CC) ?? string.Empty).Split(';');
            var bccAddresses = ((item.Mail_BCC) ?? string.Empty).Split(';');
            var totalAddresses = 0;
            var fotmattingInfo = c.GetMailHeaderFooterByCompany(item.CompanyId ?? 0);

            try
            {
                var attachments = r.GetMailAttachmentsByMailId(item.Mail_ID);
                var attachmentsCloud = r.GetMailAttachmentsCloudByMailId(item.Mail_ID).ToList();

                using (var mailMsg = new MailMessage
                {
                    From = new MailAddress(item.MailAgent_FromEmail, item.MailAgent_FromName),
                    Subject = item.Mail_Subject,
                    SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                    Body = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", fotmattingInfo.Header, item.Mail_Body, fotmattingInfo.Footer),
                    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                })
                {
                    // attachments
                    foreach (var att in attachments.Where(x => x.Filename() != string.Empty))
                    {
                        mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(att.Filename()));
                    }

                    foreach (var attCloud in attachmentsCloud.Where(x => x.DocumentId > 0))
                    {
                        using (var s = new MemoryStream(LayerFiles.CloudFileMethods.GetUniqueFile(string.Empty, attCloud.Document.CloudFileName)))
                        {
                            mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(s, attCloud.Document.Document_Filename, attCloud.Document.Content_Type));
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var addressTo in toAddresses.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))) // to addresses
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            mailMsg.To.Add(addressTo);
                            totalAddresses++;
                        }
                        catch (FormatException e0)
                        {
                            logger.Info(e0.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var addressCC in ccAddresses.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))) // cc addresses
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            mailMsg.CC.Add(addressCC);
                            totalAddresses++;
                        }
                        catch (FormatException e1)
                        {
                            logger.Info(e1.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var addressBCC in bccAddresses.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))) // bcc addresses
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            mailMsg.Bcc.Add(addressBCC);
                            totalAddresses++;
                        }
                        catch (FormatException e2)
                        {
                            logger.Info(e2.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    //client creds
                    var basicAuthenticationInfo = new NetworkCredential(item.MailAgent_Username, item.MailAgent_Password);

                    using (var client = new SmtpClient()
                    {
                        Port = item.MailAgent_Port ?? 25,
                        Host = item.MailAgent_SMTP,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo,
                        EnableSsl = item.MailAgent_UseSSL ?? false
                    })
                    {
                        //For Synchronous Execution....
                        client.Send(mailMsg);
                    }
                }

                if (item.Mail_ID > 0)
                {
                    MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 3, "OK");
                }
            }

            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);
                if (item.TaskId != null)
                {
                    TaskMethods.UpdateFailure(item.TaskId, true);
                }

                logger.Info(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);
                if (item.TaskId != null)
                {
                    TaskMethods.UpdateFailure(item.TaskId, true);
                }

                logger.Info(ex.Message);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MailMethods.UpdateMessageState(item.Mail_ID, 2, ex.Message);
                if (item.TaskId != null)
                {
                    TaskMethods.UpdateFailure(item.TaskId, true);
                }

                logger.Info(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Info(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```